# Does Shyvana q proc Hydra twice?

Tags: league-of-legends

As the title says, does Shyvana's q proc [Ravenous Hydra's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ravenous_Hydra) passive [Cleave](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Named_item_effect#Cleave) twice? Since her q essentially counts as two auto attacks (instant kill wards for example), then would each "auto" from her q proc Hydra?

Answer (score 0):

Shyvana's Q is essentially 2 auto attacks, and thus applies on hit effects twice. Any on hit effects (eg. Wits End, BotRK, and Hydra) will occur twice as well, with the exception of ones with a cooldown (like Trinity Force).